# VBA - Count Data within a Date Range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a script where i can count the data from a column if the data duplicate is `>3` i will tag it..

My problem is that i need to put a conditional statement where i can count the data within a date range of *1 Month*..

Sample Input File:: (mm/dd/yyyy)

```
Column A | Column B | Column C| Column D
023      | 1/2/2016 |         |   
023      | 1/3/2016 |         |    
023      | 1/4/2016 |         |    
024      | 2/1/2016 |         |
024      | 3/1/2016 |         |
024      | 4/1/2016 |         |
```

Sample Output File:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C| Column D
023      | 1/2/2016 |         |   
023      | 1/3/2016 |         |    
023      | 1/4/2016 |   1     |    3
024      | 2/1/2016 |         |
024      | 3/1/2016 |         |
024      | 4/1/2016 |         |
```

If the duplicate data is not within a month range it will not be tag..

***What i expect the code to do*** is count the data from `Column A` if the data is >3 and the date of all that data from `Column B` is within a month tag it from `Column D` and `E` not all the row but the recent date from `Column B`

***What my code do*** is count the data from `Column A` if the data is `>3` it will be tag from `Column C` and `D` from most recent date from Column B

***My code:***

```
Dim i1 As Long, lastRow As Long, countRow As Long

    lastRow = Sheet2.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'xDate = Sheet2.Range("C" & lastRow)

    For i1 = 1 To lastRow

    If countRow > 2 Then
        countRow = Application.CountIf(Sheet2.Columns(20), Sheet2.Cells(i1, 20))
        If countRow > 2 Then
            If Not CBool(Application.CountIfs(Sheet2.Columns(20), Sheet2.Cells(i1, 20), _
                                    Sheet2.Columns(85), ">" & Sheet2.Cells(i1, 85))) Then _
                Sheet2.Cells(i1, 86).Resize(1, 2) = Array("1", "3")
            End If
        End If
    Next i1
```

**Note:**

- In my code i didn't use `Column` `A` `B` `C` `D` instead it's `Column` `T` `CG` `CH` `CI`

I don't know how to range it to a month,  i tried collection but still new to VBA and I'm not familiar with it and i don't know if it's the right thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited**: left only code as per last OP's specs and with a formula correction

you could try this

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn_C3ter()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("duplicates")   '<~~ you should know what workbook and worksheet you are on!!
    With .Range("T1").Resize(.Range("T" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) ' the "base" column is column "T"
        With .Offset(, 67) ' column "CI" is 67 columns away from column "T"
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIFS(C20, RC20, C72,""<="" & EOMONTH(RC72,0), C72,"">="" & EOMONTH(RC72,-1)+1 )>2,    IF(COUNTIFS(C20, RC20,C72,"">"" &RC72,C72,""<="" & EOMONTH(RC72,0))=0,                   3   , """")      , """")" ' substituted relative references with absolute ones : column "T" has index 20, column "BT" has index 72
            .Value = .Value '<== if you want to get rid of formulas
        End With
        With .Offset(, 66) ' column "CH" is 66 columns away from column "T"
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]>0, 1, """") " ' I left relative references since columnn "CH" is always one left of column "CG" as was for columns "A" and "B"
            .Value = .Value '<== if you want to get rid of formulas
         End With
   End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for including the get rid of formulas your so kind!.. out of curiosity if im going to change the columns `A` `B` `C` `D` to `T` `CG` `CG` `CH` ?

Comment: see edited code to satisfy "curiosity". If I fulfilled your question, please mark my answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: well, that you can easily and quickly find it by yourself

Comment: read the comments I left to let you handle any possible change in columns reference, between them there is _column "T" has index 20, column "CG" has index 85_. so if you need to change "CG" into "BT" you have to substitute every occurrence of 85 with the index column of any new column you want to point to

Comment: i just noticed in column `CI` it returns how many value it count, e.g if there's 5 duplicate it tag as 5, how can i make it into a specific value like "3"

Comment: the part that writes the counting is `,  COUNTIFS(C20, RC20)   ,` in the first `.FormulaR1C1 =` statement. so just change it to `,  3  ,` (spacings just for readability purposes)

Comment: see edited code. other than changing columns references as per your last specs I also updated the the first `FormulaR1C1` to take into account that column "T" values can occur not in subsequent ranges

Comment: thank you so much, i keep on wondering why theres no data from `CH` , `Ci` then i comment out every functions...

Answer (score 1):

This input ...

[image]

generated this output ...

[image]

from this code ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim iLoop As Long, jLoop As Long
Dim lastRow As Long, countRow As Long
Dim myDate1 As Variant, myDate2 As Variant

    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For iLoop = 1 To lastRow
        countRow = Application.CountIf(Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(iLoop, 1), Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 1)), Sheet1.Cells(iLoop, 1))
        If countRow > 2 Then
            For jLoop = lastRow To (iLoop + 1) Step -1
                If Sheet1.Cells(jLoop, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value Then
                    myDate1 = Application.EDate(Sheet1.Cells(iLoop, 2), 3)
                    myDate2 = Sheet1.Cells(jLoop, 2)
                    If myDate2 > myDate1 Then Sheet1.Cells(jLoop, 3).Resize(1, 2) = Array("1", "3")
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next jLoop
        End If
    Next iLoop
End Sub
```

Specifically, using the worksheet function EDate to add three months to the first date found for a given item number.

Also, shortening the size of the list the worksheet function CountIf uses as the loop counter iLoop progresses.

As an aside, in your code snippet you used `i1` as a loop counter. It is easy to confuse this with `il`. 8)

Comment: My Excel is interpreting the date as m/d/yyyy. It seems yours is interpreting as d/m/yyyy.

Comment: it reads the date _"per month"_ , it should 1month only or 30days.. :(

Comment: If you don't want month, but 30 day periods, then instead of using EDate, just add 30*number of months. If you want 2 months, add 60. `myDate1 = Sheet1.Cells(iLoop, 2) + 60`

Comment: what is the purpose of `mydate2`? it's working but if i have date of _jan1_ _jan2_ _jan3_ _feb4_ the one that will be tag is _feb4_ instead of _jan3_ i wonder why??